# execute two parameters in order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Part of my query look like this,

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
*
FROM
    (select L.LOG_ID
    ,L.PAT_ID
    ,t.PANEL_START_TIME
    ,'Row' = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by l.pat_id order by panel_start_time)
    from or_log l
    inner join PATIENT p ON p.PAT_ID = l.PAT_ID
    left join OR_LOG_PANEL_TIME1 t on t.LOG_ID = l.LOG_ID and t.PANEL_TIME_EVENT_C = x
    where p.PAT_MRN_ID = @PatMRN AND l.surgery_date = @SurgDate                                 
    AND l.CASE_CLASS_C IN ('xx', 'xx')
    )a
```

If I have two parameters and each of them have multiple values,

```
@MRN = 1, 2, 3
@SurgDate = 2012, 2013, 2014
```

Is there any ways I can pass the parameters to query in order?

```
1 2012 first parameter            
2 2013 2nd                          
3 2014 3rd
```

then generate the following output

```
PatMRN   SurgDate     ORD_NUM_VALUE
  1          2012         3
  2          2013         3
  3          2014         3
```

Comment: You can pass table valued parameter and join on it.

Comment: Is it 2008 or 2012? In this case it doesn't matter since the answer will still be table valued parameters, but for other qeustions please use only tge relevant tags.

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple result sets based on the values of your parameters???

Comment: Sean, yes. I am trying get the multiple results based on the values of two parameters.

Comment: You have a problem with your design if that is what you are trying to do. That is NOT how relational data should be dealt with. What you should do is get a single result set with ALL the data and then you can manipulate that however you need to in your application. The only way you would be able to get multiple result sets would be using dynamic sql and loops and that is a recipe for disaster and horrendous performance. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a table variable:

```
declare @t table(mrn int, surg int)
insert into @t values
(1,2012),
(2,2012),
(3,2014)
```

Now you can rewrite your statement:

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
*
FROM
    (select L.LOG_ID
    ,L.PAT_ID
    ,t.PANEL_START_TIME
    ,'Row' = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by l.pat_id order by panel_start_time)
    from or_log l
    inner join PATIENT p ON p.PAT_ID = l.PAT_ID
    left join OR_LOG_PANEL_TIME1 t on t.LOG_ID = l.LOG_ID and t.PANEL_TIME_EVENT_C = x
    join @t t on t.mrn = p.PAT_MRN_ID AND t.surg = l.surgery_date
    Where l.CASE_CLASS_C IN ('xx', 'xx')
    )a
```

Now you want to know that you can create custom table valued type:

```
CREATE TYPE MRNType AS TABLE 
    ( mrn int,
      surg int);
GO
```

And use it in proc for example:

```
Create someProc
@t MTNType
AS
....
your statement
....
```

And use this proc as:

```
declare @t MRNType

insert into @t values
(1,2012),
(2,2012),
(3,2014)

Exec someProc @t = @t
```